# What program is my professor asking me to write [no code please]?

Tags: c#

> Write a program in which you declare an array of five integers and store five values in the array. Write a try block in which you place a loop that attempts to access each element of the array, **incrementing a subscript from 0 to 10.** Create a catch block that catches the eventual IndexOutOfRangeException; within the block, display “Now you’ve gone too far.” on the screen. Save the file as GoTooFar.cs.

I'm asking this because I don't understand what the bolded quote means. My English is a little bit terrible so that's why I don't understand the vocabulary really well.

I Cannot contact him this weekend and it is due before class starts on Monday.

EDIT: Thanks for the clarifications.

Comment: relevant bit is "a loop that attempts to access each element of the array, incrementing a subscript from 0 to 10." - in other words a loop that goes from 0 to 10

Comment: @MitchWheat The part I don't understand is that part :(

Comment: I like the approach. He is trying to understand not trying to get the homework done. So I think that in this case we should give an help. Your teacher is trying to force your code to fail and trying to teach you how to handle a failure caused by an IndexOutOfRange. If you declare an array with 5 elements and loop for 10 the result is an exception that you need to handle.

Comment: @Steve: please cut&paste it as an answer, it really is.

Comment: I thought it was a little bit weird to use the word *subscript*. I would've said *index* or *counter*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an array[5], correct?
Example

```
2
5
1
0
9
```

Now he's asking to make a loop from 0(because the array/List start from 0 and **NOT** 1) to 10 but you have only 5 values.So when you try to access to the six element of array the CIL will get to you an Exception for this reason you must implement the new loop in a try/cacth block. In catch block you can catch a generic exception `Exception ex` but in this case you know what Exception is(`IndexOutOfRangeException ex`).

**EDIT 1**

If you want do the program better I suggest to check if the input is correct because if the user type a string(example `"goofy"`) and the Exception is not managed you will get a runtime error. There are three options(for your exercise I suggest the first)

- Put the load loop in a try catch block(I think that now for you is
  the best option)
- You can use int.TryParse(int, out int) (It's something like try catch
  but it's a bit complex)
- You can use Regex(I don't suggest touse this because for your skills
  at the moment it's too complex)

Answer (score 4):

Use a for loop that goes from `0..10`? 
It will loop through the first 5 elements in the array and then throw `IndexOutOfRangeException` which you are supposed to catch.

Answer (score 2):

It means that you should make a loop that counts from 0 to 10, and use the loop counter as index when you access items from the array inside the loop.

Usually when you loop through the items in an array, you use the length of the array to determine how far you should loop. In this case you should not do that, as the point of the exercise is to loop outside the valid indexes of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Thank-you so much everybody. If any of you need the code for the future then here is the code.

```
        numbers[0] = 1;
        numbers[1] = 5;
        numbers[2] = 4;
        numbers[3] = 9;
        numbers[4] = 3;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                textBox1.AppendText(numbers[i].ToString() + "\n");
            }

            catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Now you're gone too far.");
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I don't think it matters, but the professor said explicitly "a try block **in which** you place a loop". This code would be a loop in which you placed a try block :) But frankly I think your code is more robust, because it doesn't immediately jump out of the loop, possibly allowing you to correct error and continue looping.

Comment: @DavidS. Thanks. Well, I wish this Stack Overflow had a Private Message system for simple questions.